# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 on 256GB on Solid State Drive and 2TB Solid State Hybrid Drive with replacing Windows 10 and partitioning?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, ssd, sshd

I have a 256 GB solid state drive and a 2 TB solid state hybrid drive. I have seen references in some web sites where they came up with same question but I don't know with or without replacing Windows.

I need with replacing Windows on my laptop. And also my laptop has only 256 GB solid state drive with pre-installed Windows 10 on it. Now I don't know whether to install Ubuntu 18.04 on this solid state drive and after complete installation then add 2 TB hybrid drive or first add 2 TB hybrid drive and install Ubuntu 18.04 then how to do Windows replacing Ubuntu without partitioning the drives.

How to partition solid state drive and also hybrid drive while installing Ubuntu?

Additional Info: I am using Ubuntu with 256 GB solid state drive and 2 TB hybrid drive for machine learning and deep learning purpose.

Comment: I have seen few similar questions but mine must have 1) replacing existing windows 2) partitioning with both solid state drive and hybrid drive

Comment: When you use Ubuntu installer, use the `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10`, so your computer would have Windows and Ubuntu in dual-boot

Comment: Would it work for you to put Windows on the larger drive and put Ubuntu on the smaller drive? (or vice versa). Easiest to only have the target drive connected when installing. If you make the Ubuntu drive the first drive in BIOS, you can sudo update-grub  when both drives are installed to add Windows to the grub boot menu without harming Window's bootloader.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But i don't need Windows at all. Only Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the installer is run from the live USB, the user is prompted with install options. During this process it is possible to select which drive to install on. Whether to install alongside, or delete and install over the top of the current operating system. There are advanced options to set up partitions. If the boot drive that you wish to install on is already inside of the machine, then it is possible to install to that drive, and after installing the system you can add another drive to the system for data, etc, however the secondary drive will not be expanded storage of the boot drive.

Comment: Thank You Mr.Douglas, so it is helpful for me to install Ubuntu in the boot drive that is already inside machine with replacing Ubuntu with Windows then after adding my 2 TB hybrid drive. But after this adding will there be any process to create partitions or need not necessary partitions after all?

Comment: If your 2TB drive is only for data, and and if the drive is pre formatted to something Ubuntu can recognize then likely you will not need to do anything to use the drive. If you do need to format the secondary drive, you can do that using "Disks" in Ubuntu.

Comment: After formatting hybrid drive then I understand that Ubuntu will recognize and add it to ~media/user_name but is it possible to add this to home/user_name. If so, how?